de Rham cohomology is isomorphic to the harmonic forms on compact Kähler manifolds
Corollary 3.2.12 in Huybrechts's Complex Geometry states that the de Rham cohomology on compact Kähler manifolds can be decomposed in terms of the Dolbeault cohomology:
$$
H^k(X, \mathbb{C}) \cong \bigoplus_{p+q=k} H^{p,q}(X).
$$
The proof starts by stating that $H^k(X, \mathbb{C}) = \mathcal{H}^k(X)$, where $\mathcal{H}^k(X)$ denotes the harmonic forms on $X$. Why is this true?
My understanding is that, using the Hodge decomposition, every form $\omega$ on $X$ can be expressed as the sum of a harmonic form, a $d$-exact form, and a $d^*$-exact form: $\omega = h + a + b$. When $\omega \in H^k(X, \mathbb{C}),$ we are modding out the $d$-exact forms, resulting in $\omega = h + b$. Since $\omega$ is closed and $X$ is compact, we can apply the $\partial \bar{\partial}$-lemma to conclude that $b$ is also $d$-exact. Thus, $\omega = h$, leading to $H^k(X, \mathbb{C}) = \mathcal{H}^k(X)$.
I am somewhat confused because the derivation of this fact is not explicitly mentioned in the text (and it is not entirely trivial). I just want to ensure that I have understood it correctly. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.
edit*
I realize the above argument doesn't make sense.
Is the argument the same as in the case of $\mathcal{H}^{p,q}(X)\cong H^{p,q}(X) $?

Wait, that doesn't make sense $\partial \partial $ lemma doesn't apply on $d^*$, this isn't right.

Does this answer your question? Correspondence between $H^1_{dR}$ and harmonic 1-forms (The post gives a proof for one form, but the proof is the same for general $k$ form)
